# Lexical Editor: How to replace selected line of text

Tags: reactjs, lexicaljs

I am looking to replace a selected text with multiple lines, but I am unable to find the exact solution in the documentation or stackoverflow.

Here is my code:

```
editor.update(() => {
    const paragraphNode = $createParagraphNode();
    const newNode = $createTextNode(popoverContent);
    paragraphNode.append(newNode);

    // How can I replace the selected nodes/text with paragraphNode? \*/
});
```

This is the input from Editor, first line of `a` is not selected

```
ab
cde 
fghi 
jklmn
```

I want to exclude the letter "a" from the replacement process. Could someone please provide guidance on how to achieve this?